# display just 10 items in custom template

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i have this template in wordpress,  i would like to just display 10 items, because right now in general options in wordpress i have 5 items but i would like to make an exception with this template i dont know where i have to modify the code in order to show in this template 10 items:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog List
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>

<div id="content" class="podcast_archive">

        <!--<div class="podcast_full">-->

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <header><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                    <h1><?php _e( 'El Jurado del Pueblo' , 'ss-podcasting' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <?php
                $feed_url = trailingslashit( home_url() ) . '?feed=podcast';
                $custom_feed_url = get_option('ss_podcasting_feed_url');
                if( $custom_feed_url && strlen( $custom_feed_url ) > 0 && $custom_feed_url != '' ) {
                    $feed_url = $custom_feed_url;
                }
                $itunes_url = str_replace( array( 'http:' , 'https:' ) , 'itpc:' , $feed_url );
                ?>

                <section>

                    <?php
                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php
                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID() , 'series' );
                        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                            $series_id = $term->term_id;
                            $series = $term->name;
                            break;
                        }
                        ?>

                        <article class="podcast_episode">

                            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>
                                <a>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'podcast-thumbnail' , array( 'class' => 'podcast_image' , 'alt' => get_the_title() , 'title' => get_the_title() ) ); ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <h3>
                                <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                                <div class="podcast_meta"><?php echo $series; ?><aside></div>
                            </h3>

<div id="audio">
<?php global $ss_podcasting;
$enclosure = $ss_podcasting->get_enclosure( get_the_ID() );
if( $enclosure ) {
    $audio_player = $ss_podcasting->audio_player( $enclosure );
    echo $audio_player;
} ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<div id="audioinfo">
<a>">Descargar Audio</a>
<span class="audiometa">
Tamaño: <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'filesize', true) ?>
</span>
</div>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[divider]');?>
</article>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>

                </section>

            <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <div class="podcast_clear"></div>

        </div>

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    </div><!-- .content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
?>
```

i would some advise so i can do it by myself :)
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the query_posts() function for that, just before your loop.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'showposts' => '10' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: doesnt work that shows all my posts of other categories :( not that template i have

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it was for a specific query. The new edit should preserve your original query, and add the showpost limit for you

Comment: `query_posts()` isn't really recommended anymore. See here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/22599

Comment: Henry, I agree that the pre_get_posts() filter is a great alternative for pages with multiple Loop's with a dependent functions.php file but for a single category page to have functionality added by a filter rather than a direct call feels (to me) to be overkill. In this case, it's a matter of keeping the code simple.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to modify your template's query. I'd suggest making use of the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class. For example:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Loop item here
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // No results found
}
```

Comment: but how i can adapt it to my own template ?

Comment: this is my loop
     <?php
     /* Start the Loop */
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php
      $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID() , 'series' );
      foreach( $terms as $term ) {
       $series_id = $term->term_id;
       $series = $term->name;
       break;
      }
      ?>

Answer (score 1):

if
`$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 10
);`

not work than check at back-end under Setting->Reading there is a "Blog pages show at most" if there is 5 post than it display only 5 post.